# Re-exporting something in transformed babel code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, babeljs

I'm developing a framework and a bundler. The bundler converts ES6 module code to CommonJS with babel's `@babel/preset-env` preset.

For the framework, I have 3 folders, `dom`, `reactive`, and `framework`.

`framework` imports all exports from `dom` and `reactive` and re-exports them.

Like so:

```js
export {
  useState,
  createEffect,
} from '../reactive/index.js'

export {
  createElement,
  createComponent,
  convertToNode,
  insert,
  render
} from '../dom/index.js'
```

That way, you can import everything you need from `framework` when using the framework.

Example Use-case:

```js
import { useState } from 'framework';

const Component = () => {
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);
  //...rest of component...
}
```

However, when I re-export my bundled code throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property useState of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

I know *why* it's doing this (because babel creates exports with only a getter), but I need to know how to get around it/structure my project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this,

1. Switched to the plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`
2. Set `loose: true` in plugin settings

Like this:

```
const { code } = babel.transformSync(beforeCode, {
  plugins: [ ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
    loose: true,
  }] ],
});
```